# Printing array in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that takes integers as command line arguments, squares them and then shows the squares and the sum of the squares. Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# = 0 ]
    then 
        echo "Enter some numbers"
    exit 1
fi

sumsq=0 #sum of squares  
int=0 #Running sum initialized to 0  
count=0 #Running count of numbers passed as arguments  

while (( $# != 0 )); do 
    numbers[$int]=$1            #Assigns arguments to integers array
    square=$(($1*$1))           #Operation to square argument first arg by itself
    squares[$int]=$square       #Square of each argument
    sumsq=$((sumsq + square))   #Add square to total
    count=$((count+1))          #Increment count
    shift                       #Remove the used argument
done

echo "The squares are ${squares[@]}"
echo "The sum of the squares is $sumsq"
exit 0
```

I have it all working as it should except for the end where I need to display the squares. It is only printing the last square for some reason. I've tried changing `e${squares[@]}"` to `${squares[*]}"`, as well as double-quoting it, but it still only prints the last square. At some point, it printed the first square (which is expected) but I must have made a change somewhere and now it only seems to print the last one.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you don't suck at programming, you should increment `int` inside the loop.

Comment: Include the statement `int=count` in the while loop construct after `count` statement.

Comment: If you could let us know complete requirement then I am pretty sure we could try to help you to write more efficient code may be in another languages too.

Comment: One advise on is to change `(( $# != 0 ))` to `(($#))` should give you the same behaviour of the the test.

Comment: but that does not fix your problem... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy thing to do is simply delete the `int` variable altogether and replace it with `count` which you already increment within your loop, e.g.

```
sumsq=0 #sum of squares
count=0 #Running count of numbers passed as arguments

while (( $# != 0 )); do
    numbers[$count]=$1          #Assigns arguments to integers array
    square=$(($1*$1))           #Operation to square argument first arg by itself
    squares[$count]=$square     #Square of each argument
    sumsq=$((sumsq + square))   #Add square to total
    count=$((count+1))          #Increment count
    shift                       #Remove the used argument
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

Making the change above:

```
$ bash squares.sh 1 2 3 4
The squares are 1 4 9 16
The sum of the squares is 30
```

(no, you don't such at programming, that's one issue new script writers could stare at for hours and not see -- and why running with `bash -x scriptname` to debug is helpful)

---

**Update Following Comment Re: Difficulty**

Above I only posted the changes needed. If it is not working for you, then I suspect a typo somewhere. Here is the complete script you can simply save and run:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]
    then
        echo "Enter some numbers"
    exit 1
fi

sumsq=0 #sum of squares
count=0 #Running count of numbers passed as arguments

while (( $# != 0 )); do
    numbers[$count]=$1          #Assigns arguments to integers array
    square=$(($1*$1))           #Operation to square argument first arg by itself
    squares[$count]=$square     #Square of each argument
    sumsq=$((sumsq + square))   #Add square to total
    count=$((count+1))          #Increment count
    shift                       #Remove the used argument
done

echo "The squares are ${squares[@]}"
echo "The sum of the squares is $sumsq"
exit 0
```

As per the example above, run the script as:

```
bash squares.sh 1 2 3 4
```

(replace `squares.sh` with whatever name you gave to the file) If you have any problems, let me know because this is working quite well here, e.g.

```
bash squares.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The squares are 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
The sum of the squares is 285
```

Comment: I tried running this but it still only printed the first square for me, is there anything I need to change in the echo statement?

Comment: You did add the rest of your script to it -- right? I just posted the updated lines, not the whole script. See how I invoke the script: `bash squares.sh 1 2 3 4`. Works like a champ here. Run it with `bash -x squares.sh 1 2 3 4` and see where you are running into problems. I suspect a typo. I'll add the entire script.

Comment: Why use an explicit index *at all*, when you can run `squares+=( "$square" )` to append to the end without knowing the index number?

Comment: Yes, correct you are, I was attempting to stick to what the OP had for the most part (so he could follow his own logic, etc...), but I would do it as you indicate were I rewriting from scratch. It was either a tweak what he had or scratch it and rewrite thing..

Comment: *nod*. I see a lot of folks who simply don't *know* that they can use `+=` to extend an array (it didn't exist in early versions of bash), so it's often worth including.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I had added the rest of the script back in but I was invoking it with ./script.sh. I'll check out the updated script in a few hours and report back, thanks again for the help!

Comment: You bet, glad to help. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $# in
  0) printf 'give me something!' >&2; exit 1;;  ##: If no argument given exit!
esac

sumsq=0 #sum of squares
int=0 #Running sum initialized to 0
count=0 #Running count of numbers passed as arguments

while (( $# )); do
  case $1 in
    *[!0-9]*) printf '%s is not an integer!' >&2 "$1"  ##: If argument is not an int. exit!
      exit 1;;
  esac
  numbers[$((int++))]=$1      #Assigns arguments to integers array increment int by one
  square=$(($1*$1))           #Operation to square argument first arg by itself
  squares[$((int++))]=$square #Square of each argument increment int by one
  sumsq=$((sumsq + square))   #Add square to total
  count=$((count++))          #Increment count
  shift                       #Remove the used argument
done

echo "The squares are ${squares[@]}"
echo "The sum of the squares is $sumsq"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Would you mind explaining why `"The squares are ${squares[@]}"` works in your script but not in mine?

Comment: @isuckatprogramming, because in your original script you're overwriting `squares[0]` over and over because you never increase `int`.

Comment: @isuckatprogramming, yes I did increment the int, your code did not. so every loop it is overwritten by the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over given arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
for N in "$@"; {          # iterate over args
    squares+=( $((N*N)) ) # will create and then apend array squares
}
sqstr="${squares[@]}"          # create string from array
echo "The squares are $sqstr"  # string of squares will be substituted
echo "The sum of the squares is $((${sqstr// /+}))" # string  will be substituted,
                                                    # spaces  will be changed to +
                                                    # and sum will be calculated
```

Usage

```
$ ./test 1 2 3 4 5
The squares are 1 4 9 16 25
The sum of the squares is 55
```

Updated version

```
#!/bin/bash
for N do squares+=($((N*N))); done # iterate over args, create and then apend array squares
sqstr="${squares[@]}"              # create string from array
echo "The squares are $sqstr"      # string of squares will be substituted
echo "The sum of the squares is $((${sqstr// /+}))" # string  will be substituted,
                                                    # spaces  will be changed to +
                                                    # and sum will be calculated
```

Comment: Why the unquoted `$@`, making your argument list's length vulnerable to changes coming from string-splitting and glob expansion? Fewer bugs to just use `for N do`, as it implicitly loops over `"$@"`, or `for N in "$@"; do` (in either case, using *documented* `for` syntax rather than an undocumented extension).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!